# flyway 3.3 migrations with postgresql and postgis extension

Tags: postgresql, postgis, flyway

I am at my wits end, and I don't what else I can try.   I am trying to do a flyway clean on my local database.  I have Postgres 9.4 latest with latest PostGIS extension.  I am using the public schema to store 10 tables, and 7 sequences ... it's very small.

Now I am trying to do a simple FlywayDB 3.3 clean instruction with maven.  I have the username and password and public schema listed in the maven configuration file.  I constantly kept getting errors to suggest various views and tables are used by the PostGIS extension, so it won't delete them.

So, a search here, and on the Internet in general suggested I do:
ALTER USER myuser WITH SUPERUSER;       This did not solve my problems.

In other research, it was suggested to use another schema for data, and not the public schema.  So, I created a new schema for my app, and moved over my sequences and tables, including table spatial_ref_sys.  I updated the maven config to clean only this new schema ... but it says it cannot delete "spatial_ref_sys" because it is used by PostGIS.

I have 10 tables uses for my app, with 7 sequences ... I just want Flyway to clean my database, so I can try the baseline file to rebuild it.  I am no expert in PostGIS, so I don't know if I can remnove that table without killing any spatial functionality I want to use in the future.

Thanks for any help, and please let me know if I can provide any other data.

Comment: I had this problem for test environment, see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46656531#51038385

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known issue with no trivial solution but 2 good workarounds: https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/100

Answer (score 2):

As noted it's a known issue with [flyway](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/100).

adding a file called `beforeClean.sql` with the statement:

```
   DROP EXTENSION IF EXISTS PostGIS;
```

Solves the problem